# WSO2 IS expose secondary user store as ldap

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I would like to expose users configured in a secondary user store in WSO2 IS as an ldap. I found out that WSO2 IS has its own internal ldap but just for primary user store, and secondary user stores are not available through this method.

I couldn't find any ldap connector neither.

Is there a way to do this OOB?

Cheers

Comment: As the description we understand that you are asking how to configure a secondary user store for WSO2 identity server. Could you please verify is this the requirement?

Comment: No, I want to add an ldap as a secondary user store and expose is in IS through another ldap. In other ways, to make the IS an ldap proxy.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any explicit connector to configure an LDAP server as Primary or Secondary userstore of the Identity Server. It's supported out of the box.

1. If you want to add your LDAP as the Primary userstore of the WSO2 server, you can configure the "ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager" in the `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/user-mgt.xml` file. [Documentation](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/setup/configuring-a-read-write-ldap-user-store/) WSO2 Identity Server does come with an OOB in-built LDAP server configured as the primary user store. This can also be confiured as a secondary user store if you want. But, please note that it's NOT recommended to use this embedded LDAP server in the production. You should configure an external dedicated LDAP server in production.
2. You can also add LDAP servers as secondary user stores from the Management Console. [Documentation](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/setup/configuring-secondary-user-stores/) If you want to test adding an LDAP server as the secondary, you can try that by pointing the same in-built LDAP server. Just copy the LDAP server configs from the `user-mgt.xml` and fill the details in the Management Console. Again, it's recommended to use an external LDAP server in production.

   3. If you are using 5.9.0 or above, PRIMARY user store configurations should be done in the `deployment.toml` file which will get reflected in the `user-mgt.xml` file after a restart. Any lower, you should change the configs directly in the `user-mgt.xml` file. Secondary userstores can be configured from the Management Console in all the versions.
   4. In case you are interested in configuring the in-built LDAP as a secondary user store; Either you can change the PRIMARY to JDBC User store and use the in-built LDAP as a secondary. Or else, you can start another Identity Server(with a port offset to avoid port conflicts), which will expose another LDAP server. Then, point your secondary LDAP to that server's in-built LDAP.